# does google crawl flash

Tags: flash, web-crawler

i have one domain

[link text](http://www.premiers.ae/)

i want to know that does google crawl flash like in the intro of mentioned website

thanks

Comment: This seems kind of spammy.  And not really programming related.

Comment: why spam ? i even delete domain name from question if any probelm ....

Comment: Google doesn't crawl them. Besides, Flash intros are soooo 1990s.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Just in case it's not spam: no, it doesn't crawl flash content at all.

Comment: Yes it does: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/06/improved-flash-indexing.html and http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2008/06/google-learns-to-crawl-flash.html

Comment: +1 Oy, that was new for me. Actually, I've never seen any google search result in any flash content. Someone pls. point me one.